# ContextMenuStrip Is Available On NotifyIcon, But Not ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I'm adding a ContextMenu to a WinForm application and I want to associate it to a NotifyIcon.  The issue is the NotifyIcon's properties only include ContextMenuStrip and not ContextMenu.

How can I add a ContextMenu to my icon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.contextmenu.aspx) I see it has a ContextMenu property.  What version of .Net are you using?  Perhaps you are looking at the property grid?  You might have to set that property in code.

Comment: Bingo.  Notice the `[Browsable(False)]` attribute.  This property is supported back in .NET 2.0 as well.